# Where is my ipy.exe?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I've got clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate, VS 2010 professional, and latest IronPython installed. In VS I can create an IronPython project just fine (seems like the install is ok), but when I try to run the project (a simple print), I get this error message:

```
Interpreter "C:\Program Files\...\0.4\ipy.exe" does not exist.
```

I have no prior experience with IronPython, I might be making a silly mistake here. I realised I should install python too, I did, version 2.7 and 3.1, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on project - In the properties, provide the Interpreter path to whereever your ipy.exe is located.

C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe?

Comment: You can also execute it by clicking on Debug/Execute Project in IronPython Interactive

Comment: That solution did not work as intended, I simply copied the ipy.exe to the given path, now it seems to be running just fine.Thanks for help!